# Express.js send() will not prompt download through email client

Tags: node.js, express, xlsx, exceljs

I have an api that I'm testing at the moment.  I'm using `ngrok` to make my local server that has the api code visible to the internet.  If, for example, I have a link like `http://something.ngrok.io/api/spreadsheet?param1=123&param2=001,002`, what should happen when you click on that link is a spreadsheet is dynamically built using `exceljs` and sent to the client using express.  Here is that snippet of code:

```
const buffer = await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer()
res.status(200)
res.set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
res.attachment("spreadsheet.xlsx")
res.send(buffer)
```

The weird thing that I can't figure out is when you just copy and paste that `ngrok` link into your browser it prompts the spreadsheet download as I hoped would happen.  When you send someone that link through an email client and try to click it, it opens a new tab like it's going to prompt the download, but after a second or two the tab just closes and nothing else happens.  Is this because of some email client security?  Is there a way to allow the download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone that runs across this problem in the future, the issue is described [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/77421860/clicking-download-link-does-nothing-at-all?hl=en).  Turns out that ngrok by default creates an http tunnel and it needed to be https for the email client to allow the download to move forward.